# Can you receive UNC path from a browser file dialog prompt?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

We have a file upload in our ASP.NET MVC application that works fine.  It engages the browser file dialog box and performs an upload on the selected file.  Now, we're interested to receive the UNC path from the file (for different mapped drives) if possible.  Can this be done?

What we'd like to do is if it's a non local resource, we'd like to pass up the UNC path rather upload since our server could access it much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file input control will be able to use whatever the client computer can, be it UNC or local. The file will be uploaded via the client.

If you want to extract this path from the upload, this is not possible due to security considerations.

You may need to *ask* the user to input the file path to a text field in order to determine if it is local or on a network share, then decide what method to use in order to obtain the file.